# Combining nested list and normal list into a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Let's say I have two lists, where one is a nested list and the other is a normal list, how do I combine them into a dictionary?

```
[[1, 3, 5], [4, 6, 9]] # Nested list

[45, 32] # Normal list

{(1, 3, 5): 45, (4, 6, 9): 32} # The dictionary
```

I tried this but it gives me an error,

```
dictionary = dict(zip(l1, l2)))
print(dictionary)
```

Comment: @StefanPochmann Sorry I will include that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error you got was probably something like this:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

`[1, 3, 5]` and `(1, 3, 5)` are not the same. Tuples are immutable and therefore can be used as dictionary keys, but lists cannot because they can be modified.

The following will work:

```
dict(zip(map(tuple, l1), l2)))
```

Or more clearly:

```
{tuple(k): v for k, v in zip(l1, l2)}
```